# Table with tikz image: vertical alignment

Tags: tables, tabu

I'm trying to create simple table with tikz pictures and its descriptions on the left side. Unfortunately I cannot vertically center those descriptions in their cells:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot,graphicx}
\usepackage{array,multirow,tabu}
\newcolumntype{C}[3]{@{\hspace*{#1}}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#2}@{\hspace*{#3}}}
\newcolumntype{R}[2]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}@{\hspace*{#2}}}
\newcolumntype{L}[2]{@{\hspace*{#1}}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#2}}
\begin{document}

{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
\begin{tabular}{|C{0pt}{100pt}{0pt}|C{0pt}{200pt}{0pt}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|C{0pt}{100pt}{0pt}|}{Modulační signál} & \tikz \draw[domain=-(pi/2):((7/2)*pi),smooth,variable=\x,thick,scale=0.5] plot ({\x},{sin(\x r)}); \\
\hline
moduluje amplitudu nosného signálu & \tikz \draw[domain=-(pi/2):((7/2)*pi),smooth,variable=\x,thick,scale=0.5] plot ({\x},{sin(\x r)}); \\
\hline
moduluje frekvenci nosného signálu & \tikz \draw[domain=-(pi/2):((7/2)*pi),smooth,variable=\x,thick,scale=0.5] plot ({\x},{sin(\x r)}); \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}\\[1cm]

{\tabulinesep=1.2mm
\begin{tabu}{|c|c|}
\hline
Modulační signál & \tikz \draw[domain=-(pi/2):((7/2)*pi),smooth,variable=\x,thick,scale=0.5] plot ({\x},{sin(\x r)}); \\\hline
moduluje amplitudu nosného signálu & \tikz \draw[domain=-(pi/2):((7/2)*pi),smooth,variable=\x,thick,scale=0.5] plot ({\x},{sin(\x r)}); \\\hline
moduluje frekvenci nosného signálu & \tikz \draw[domain=-(pi/2):((7/2)*pi),smooth,variable=\x,thick,scale=0.5] plot ({\x},{sin(\x r)}); \\\hline
\end{tabu}}

\end{document}
```

I tried `tabular`:
[image]
and `tabu`:
[image]
environment. `tabu` gives slightly better output.
How can I vertically center those descriptions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I define a `style` which I call `my pic adjust` to be applied to each of the `\tikz` commands in the `tabular` environment:

```
\tikzset{my pic adjust/.style={%%
  baseline=(current bounding box.center),
  execute at end picture={\path (current bounding box.north) -- ++ (0,4pt);
                          \path (current bounding box.south) -- ++ (0,-4pt);
                          }%
  }}
```

The idea here is *first* to set the `baseline` for the `\tikz` command.  By default, with any picture, the baseline is at the bottom of the picture.  So, I explicitly define the baseline to be the center of the picture.  You can adjust this to something more suitable if the center isn't quite right looking to you.  *Secondly* there is no buffer around the picture and so without further adjustments the picture bumps into the horizontal lines for your table.  To get around this, I *tweak* the bounding box by adding an *offset* (of `4pt`) to the current bounding box.

However, we can do a bit better. `.style` allows allows an argument to be passed. So to facilitate fine-tuning of the picture's baseline, I modified the above code as follows:

```
\tikzset{my pic adjust/.style={%%
  baseline=(my center),
  execute at end picture={\path (current bounding box.north) -- ++ (0,4pt);
                          \path (current bounding box.south) -- ++ (0,-4pt);
                          \path (current bounding box.center) -- ++ (0,#1) coordinate (my center);
                          }%
  },
 my pic adjust/.default=0pt,
}
```

By also providing `my pic adjust/.default=0pt`, I set the default value for `my pic adjust` so that it needn't always be explicitly set if you feel no adjustment above the picture center is necessary.

Here at the end of the picture, in addition to tweaking the bounding box, I add a `coordinate` that I call `my center`, which I use for the baseline setting.  `my center` is a new coordinate displaced vertically from the center of the bounding box.

It's this lastest version of `my pic adjust` that I use here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot,graphicx}
\usepackage{array,multirow,tabu}
\newcolumntype{C}[3]{@{\hspace*{#1}}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#2}@{\hspace*{#3}}}
\newcolumntype{R}[2]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}@{\hspace*{#2}}}
\newcolumntype{L}[2]{@{\hspace*{#1}}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#2}}
\tikzset{my pic adjust/.style={%%
  baseline=(my center),
  execute at end picture={\path (current bounding box.north) -- ++ (0,4pt);
                          \path (current bounding box.south) -- ++ (0,-4pt);
                          \path (current bounding box.center) -- ++ (0,#1) coordinate (my center);
                          }%
  },
my pic adjust/.default=0pt,
}

\begin{document}

{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
\begin{tabular}{|C{0pt}{100pt}{0pt}|C{0pt}{200pt}{0pt}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|C{0pt}{100pt}{0pt}|}{Modulační signál} & 
  \tikz[my pic adjust=-2pt] \draw[domain=-(pi/2):((7/2)*pi),smooth,variable=\x,thick,scale=0.5] plot ({\x},{sin(\x r)}); \\
\hline
moduluje amplitudu nosného signálu & \tikz[my pic adjust=4pt] \draw[domain=-(pi/2):((7/2)*pi),smooth,variable=\x,thick,scale=0.5] plot ({\x},{sin(\x r)}); \\
\hline
moduluje frekvenci nosného signálu & \tikz[my pic adjust=4pt] \draw[domain=-(pi/2):((7/2)*pi),smooth,variable=\x,thick,scale=0.5] plot ({\x},{sin(\x r)}); \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}\\[1cm]

{\tabulinesep=1.2mm
\begin{tabu}{|c|c|}
\hline
Modulační signál & \tikz \draw[domain=-(pi/2):((7/2)*pi),smooth,variable=\x,thick,scale=0.5] plot ({\x},{sin(\x r)}); \\\hline
moduluje amplitudu nosného signálu & \tikz \draw[domain=-(pi/2):((7/2)*pi),smooth,variable=\x,thick,scale=0.5] plot ({\x},{sin(\x r)}); \\\hline
moduluje frekvenci nosného signálu & \tikz \draw[domain=-(pi/2):((7/2)*pi),smooth,variable=\x,thick,scale=0.5] plot ({\x},{sin(\x r)}); \\\hline
\end{tabu}}

\end{document}
```

I didn't tweak anything in the `tabu` table.  I'll leave that for you.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

by set `tizpicture` baseline to `current bounding box.center`. for additional vertical space i suggest to use gaped cell defined in the package `makecell`. as tabular environmemt can be handy `tabulary`, however it works also with `p{...}` column type:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells
\tikzset{line/.style={draw=red, very thick, domain=-pi/2:7*pi/2, samples=60}}

\begin{tabularx}{.88\linewidth}{| >{\raggedright}X | l |}
    \hline
Modulační\newline
signál
    &   \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
        \draw [line] plot (0.5*\x,{sin(\x r)});     \\
    \hline
moduluje amplitudu nosného signálu
    &   \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
        \draw[line] plot (0.5*\x,{sin(\x r)});      \\
    \hline
moduluje frekvenci nosného signálu
    &   \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
        \draw[line] plot (0.5*\x,{sin(\x r)});      \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]